# How to find the file by its partial name?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How can I get the full filename?

For example:

I have a file named `171_s.jpg` that is stored on the hard disc.

I need to find the file by its partial name, i.e. `171_s`, and get the full name.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Here's an example using GetFiles():

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string partialName = "171_s";
    DirectoryInfo hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
    FileInfo[] filesInDir = hdDirectoryInWhichToSearch.GetFiles("*" + partialName + "*.*");

    foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
    {
        string fullName = foundFile.FullName;
        Console.WriteLine(fullName);
    }    
}
```

Comment: This works great for me, but I needed to convert the FileInfo array into a string array and found that the following worked better for that: string[] filesInDir = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*" + partialName + "*.*");

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` is the preferred method these days

Comment: @hvaughan3 the FileInfo has a Name and fullname property that will give you that plus lots of other options as well you'll be better off with the infos than converting to strings

Comment: @MikeT Thanks for the info. Will have to look into that and make sure it is available on Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS. That would definitely be better than having to work with those strings.

Comment: GetFiles is a great solution but GetFiles("\*" + partialName + "\*.\*") could return more files than those OP is looking for.
in his case GetFiles(partialName + ".\*") should be enough

Comment: What if my filename is "171_sABC.jpg" and I wanted to find all files having partial name of "171_s" ? Does that code still works?

Comment: @Juran Yes. The wildcard identifiers - '*' - will ensure that 171_sABC.jpg will be picked up by the GetFiles() function. But you should use EnumerateFiles, as suggested above.

Comment: I guess it will throw an error if that partialName doesn't exists. Need to add try catch there

Answer (score 19):

Update - Jakub answer is more efficient way to do.
ie, use System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx

The answer has been already posted, however for an easy understanding here is the code

```
string folderPath = @"C:/Temp/";
DirectoryInfo dir= new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("171_s*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach (var item in files)
{
    // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx

```
public static string[] GetFiles(
    string path,
    string searchPattern,
    SearchOption searchOption
)
```

> **path**
>       Type: System.String
>       The directory to search.
>
> **searchPattern**
>       Type: System.String
>       The search string to match against the names of files in path. The parameter cannot end in two periods ("..") or contain two periods
>   ("..") followed by DirectorySeparatorChar or
>   AltDirectorySeparatorChar, nor can it contain any of the characters in
>   InvalidPathChars.
>
> **searchOption**
>       Type: System.IO.SearchOption
>       One of the SearchOption values that specifies whether the search operation should include all subdirectories or only the current
>   directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
....

List<string> _filesNames;

foreach(var file in _directory)
{
    string name = GetFileName(file);
    if(name.IndexOf(_partialFileName) > 0)
    {
      _fileNames.Add(name);   
    }
}
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that:

```
string path = @"C:\example\directory";
string searchPattern = "*171_s*";
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern,SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```