# VB.NET Path to file with unknown file extension (but known name)

Tags: vb.net

Could anyone help me with getting file path when I know file name (which is constant and won´t change) but don´t know file extension (can change depending on users selection in Excel):

```
Dim MyAppPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
Dim ExcelfilePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(MyAppPath, "bundle\" & "Rozpis.xlsm")
Dim ExcelfileBackupPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(MyAppPath, "bundle\backup\" & "Rozpis.xlsm")
```

I want it to be like this - to match any file with this particular name "Rozpis":

```
Dim MyAppPath As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    Dim ExcelfilePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(MyAppPath, "bundle\" & "Rozpis.*")
    Dim ExcelfileBackupPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(MyAppPath, "bundle\backup\" & "Rozpis.*")
```

(This code is part of simple "self-protecting" mechanism for my app.)

**What I tried:**

I looked at regex (but if there is simpler way than regex it would be better - tried filemame.* - not working) as potential option (specifically this one: /(.)+(doc|docx|pdf)$/i ) but I don´t know much how to use it. **I got error Regex cannot be converted to string** when tried to use like this:

```
// Don´t remember the code exactly - something like this:    
// regex = New Regex as regex
Dim ExcelfilePath As String = IO.Path.Combine(MyAppPath, "bundle\" & "Rozpis." & regex)
Dim ExcelfileBackupPath As String = IO.Path.Combine(MyAppPath, "bundle\backup\" & "Rozpis" & regex)
```

Comment: You can use wildcards with [`Directory.GetFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the file by its partial name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428734/how-to-find-the-file-by-its-partial-name)